# How to select from a subquery with the IN operator?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT sub_id FROM table2 WHERE value > 10)
```

How to select all columns from table2 in the main query?

P.S. I know how to do this with a JOIN, but would like to see if it is possible without it.

Comment: Which database server are you using? MySQL,MSSQL,...

Comment: @TheKNVB I am using PostgreSQL, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean outer query? is it outer join?

Comment: @TheKNVB I mean the main query, as opposed to the subquery

Comment: In order to select data from table2 it must be in the `FROM`clause, i.e. you must join it. This, however, probably means that you get a lot more result rows, for instead of getting only table1 rows that have a match in table 2, you get those rows mutliplied with their matches. (E.g. if ID 1 is twice in table2 and ID 2 is thrice in table2, you no longer get the two rows for ID 1 and 2, but the 5 joined rows.) This shouldn't come as a surprise, though, for how else would you be able to show the table2 data? :-)

Comment: Do you also want columns from `table1`?  Sample data and desired results would help.  If you "know how to do this with `JOIN`", then you should include that query in the question as well.

Answer (score 3):

- You need to use join to get columns from 2nd table.
- Here's how it can be done.

```
select * 
from table1 as t1 
join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.sub_id 
where t2.value > 10;
```

Comment: Thanks! I know how to do it with a JOIN, but prefer not to if possible.

Comment: @VictorYan Joining is basically your only option here.

Comment: @VictorYan regardless of if you use join or not you will have to get data of 2nd table in some or the other way(which also means scanning the table2 in some way ), do you mind if i ask why you want to avoid join ?

Comment: @HarshGundecha I am composing potentially very complex queries programmatically and it appears that building join queries entail many more variables than subqueries which are independent of context.

Comment: @VictorYan in that case your question could probably be how to programmatically build complex queries in easier or simpler way, apart from that if you add more technical details like the whole scenario, language, frameworks used then people would probably be able to give some direction to your expected solution.

Comment: @HarshGundecha Thanks for your helpful suggestion. I will think about it and may ask another more general question.

Answer (score -1):

Is it what you need?

```
select * 
from table1 as t1, 
table2 as t2 
where t2.value > 10 and t1.id = t2.sub_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, is this equivalent to doing a JOIN?

Comment: @Victor Yan: Yes, this is how we joined tables in the 1980s, when explicit joins had not be invented yet. This syntax has long been discouraged. Explicit joins made it into the SQL standard in 1992.